# What functions and operations are available for CartoCSS?

Tags: carto, cartocss

Where can I find a reference for the functions available for CartoCSS styling on carto.com? The documentation only gives a few examples and nowhere can I find the set of mathematical operations that can be performed.

```
#layer {
  marker-width: ramp([my_field], range(5, 25), equal(5));
  marker-fill: #AAA
  marker-fill-opacity: 0.8;
  marker-allow-overlap: true;
}
```

Can I apply a function (such as `log` or `sqrt`) to `my_field` before making the `ramp`? Where is the documentation for `ramp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ramp` is a function of [TurboCARTO](https://github.com/CartoDB/turbo-carto), a CartoCSS preprocessor developed by CARTO. You can find also short tutorials [in CARTO guides](https://carto.com/learn/guides).

Unfortunately, right now you cannot apply other functions like the ones you mentioned as arguments in `ramp` functions. The issue has been reported already by Mamata Akella (you can check it in the repository) and there is a possibility that they could be implemented in the future. In the meanwhile, you would need to create new fields with those functions using SQL and then apply the style.